# Platform www for Cordova available?

Tags: cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

[Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org) supports - besides iOS and Android - a bunch of other [Cordova platforms](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_index.md.html#Platform%20Guides).

**I wonder, if anybody knows about a [platform](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_index.md.html#Platform%20Guides) www for [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org).**

As we e.g. build for **Android** using

```
cordova build android
```

I'd like to **build for web**:

```
cordova build web
```

As a result, the Cordova project's `platform` folder should then have a subfolder `web`. There, the app might be **launched using any browser** on a desktop PC or **deployed to a web-server**.

Comment: What do you mean a platform www?

Comment: @CatalinMunteanu I refined my question.

Comment: This is not available but I think there are plans and talks to make the browser a first class platform like other mobile operating systems. Like Catalin mentioned, it is possible now, but you have to do some manual work, like stubbing out all of your Cordova calls.

Comment: BTW in the mean time, you can use `cordova serve` to start hosting that folder and easily access it from your browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no platform `www` for Cordova.

You can use your app within a browser but unless you make some changes to your code you will get a few errors.

For example all the plugins that you have for other platforms (ios, android) will be useless.

Go ahead open your app in a browser by accessing **your_workspace/project_name/www**.

It will work but depending on the complexity of your app you might get errors if some plugins or features aren't available (Cordova core will actually be useless at this moment)

Also you will need to change your `device_ready` event with `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {});` or add support for both if you choose to make your app browser-ready.

Conclusion:

With additional effort and code you can make your app usable in desktop/mobile browsers as a website. The features Cordova provides will not be of any use in this case so most of your events/listeners should have a wrapper that depending on the platform would use Cordova or browser functions.

Comment: What is the **www ^3.12.0** show when the command `cordova platform ls` is executed?

Answer (score 5):

Starting with version 3.6, Cordova adds a new platform "Browser". So the plugins will have a automatic fallback for the browser and you don't have to worry about the device_ready event.

At the moment the are only a few plugins which support the new platform, but I think this will change quickly.

See: [Browser as a platform for your PhoneGap/Cordova apps](http://web.archive.org/web/20150321095231/http://www.raymondcamden.com:80/2014/9/24/Browser-as-a-platform-for-your-PhoneGapCordova-apps).